# Module not found C++ .dll inside C# Unity on Hololens

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll, hololens

I'm trying to implement a simple .dll to my Project which will be builded for the HoloLens Augmented Reality Application. I am trying to simply call a function from my C++ .dll to implement an OpenCV Code but on the HoloLens it throws an error shown below.

.dll C++ Code:

```
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall test() {
    return;
}
```

Unity C# Code:

```
 internal class OpenCV
    {
        // Define the functions which can be called from the .dll.
        [DllImport("Project1")]
        internal static extern void test();

        public static void testmeth()
        {
            test();
        }
    }
```

Error when Debugging on HoloLens with Visual Studio:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'Project1': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'
```

Here you can see the Settings and Path of the dll:
[image: Here you can see the Settings and Path of the dll]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem:
The source files of OpenCV which I compiled for x86 and used successfully for my UWP App somehow didn't work for the HoloLens.

Solved:
I used the NuGet-Package "OpenCV-HoloLens" for my C++ .dll and copied the .dlls to Unity as well.